# API for easy to extend or override

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am developing a simple API which can allow clients to read a different type of file and save the content to the database in JAVA.

At the beginning it only supports CSV. I want to make the API easy to extend if the client they want to write their own implementation to read the CSV file or other types of files.

Which design patterns I should use to achieve this purpose?

Comment: I think talking about "design patterns" (in the OO/GoF sense of the word) is probably a bit silly in this context.  I'd suggest you probably want a REST API (regardless of whether or not you ultimately implement it in Java).  Here's some good, simple, practical advice: https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-design-step-by-step-guide-2f2c9f9fcdbf, or https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how-to-design-a-restful-api-architecture-from-a-human-language-spec.  ALSO:  "DDD": https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/ddd-oriented-microservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use strategy design pattern for this purpose.

Few good links : 
https://www.journaldev.com/1754/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial
https://www.journaldev.com/1754/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial

Comment: Strategy pattern suits well. You will need to code for interface and let the clients use the interface or provide their own implemenation to the interface for different types of files.